# Syntax error in function using dblink to replicate new data

Tags: postgresql, function, triggers, plpgsql, dblink

I never created a function in Postgres, I followed some tutorials and made this code, but I don't know why it is wrong, the error in the console is:

> ```
> "syntax error at or near "SELECT"
> LINE 5:     SELECT public.dblink_connect('hostaddr=127.0.0.1 port=54...
> ```

I'm using the version 9.3.6 on Ubuntu.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_replicate_insertof_students()
      RETURNS text AS
    $BODY$
    BEGIN
    SELECT public.dblink_connect('hostaddr=127.0.0.1 port=5433 dbname=Utiles user=postgres password=Mypass');

INSERT INTO res_partner (company_id,name,lang,comment,street,supplier,city,zip,country_id,email,phone,date,customer,mobile,ref,state_id,opt_out,city_id,l10n_mx_city2,l10n_mx_street3,l10n_mx_street4,notification_email_send,type,street2,active)
                        VALUES  (1,NEW.name,'es_MX',NEW.comment,NEW.street,false,NEW.city,NEW.zip,NEW.country_id,NEW.email,NEW.phone,NEW.date,true,NEW.mobile,NEW.ref,NEW.state_id,false,NEW.city_id,NEW.l10n_mx_city2,NEW.l10n_mx_street3,NEW.l10n_mx_street4,NEW.notification_email_send,NEW.type,NEW.street2,NEW.active));

SELECT public.dblink_disconnect();

END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE SECURITY DEFINER
SET search_path=myschema, pg_temp;


CREATE TRIGGER tr_replicate_insertof_students
  AFTER INSERT 
  ON res_partner
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE fn_replicate_insertof_students();
```

Comment: What is the exact error you get? any error code or complete error description would help

Comment: It's procedural code, so the language should be `plpgsql` and not `sql`.

Comment: Cross-posted to http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/105723/7788 apparently. Sigh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@Nick raised some good points](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31173272/939860), but there's more:

Your `search_path` is actually *done right*. `pg_catalog` is automatically included *first* unless you explicitly put it in there on a different position.

- [How does the search_path influence identifier resolution and the "current schema"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-does-the-search-path-influence-identifier-resolution-and-the-current-schema/9067777#9067777)

More importantly, the whole function is ***nonsense in its current form***. You open a dblink connection, but you don't use it. Looks like you want to throw in `dblink_exec()`. But you need to concatenate the query string with values form `NEW` first, since `NEW` is not visible on the other side of the wormhole. So you have yourself a nice example of dynamic SQL. Quite a steep start for a beginner!

Detailed code example and explanation for function with dblink in this recent related answer on dba.SE:

- [Persistant inserts in a UDF even if the function aborts](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/105186/3684)

Also, this must be a [trigger function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-trigger.html) to be used in a trigger.
Your function could work like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_replicate_insertof_students()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$func$
BEGIN
PERFORM public.dblink_connect('hostaddr=127.0.0.1 port=5433 
                dbname=Utiles user=postgres password=Mypass');

PERFORM public.dblink_exec(format(
   $f$INSERT INTO res_partner (company_id, name, lang, comment, ... )
      VALUES  (1, %L, 'es_MX', %L, ... )$f$
    , NEW.name, NEW.comment, ... ));

PERFORM public.dblink_disconnect();

RETURN NULL;  -- only ok for AFTER trigger

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE SECURITY DEFINER
                        SET search_path=myschema, pg_temp;
ALTER FUNCTION fn_replicate_insertof_students() OWNER TO postgres;  -- guessing
```

Also make sure to set the owner right for a [`SECURITY DEFINER` function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html#SQL-CREATEFUNCTION-SECURITY).

Consider using a `FOREIGN SERVER`, `USER MAPPING` and a password file on the target server. Details in [above link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-does-the-search-path-influence-identifier-resolution-and-the-current-schema/9067777#9067777).

The whole idea is a rather expensive special case of replication. For some inserts to a table, this is ok, but there are [better solutions for massive load](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/high-availability.html).

Comment: Oops... Thanks, not sure why I thought the `search_path` change was necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You have marked the function as `LANGUAGE sql`, which is only for functions containing single SQL statements. This function is written in `LANGUAGE plpgsql`.

It will still complain about the `SELECT`, because `plpgsql` requires that you actually do something with the result of a `SELECT`. You'll need to replace `SELECT` with `PERFORM`, to make it explicit that you're discarding the result.